# How do I retrieve email with Exim4?

Tags: debian, email, exim

I successfully installed and configured Exim4 on my Debian/Squeeze machine, so now I am able to send outgoing emails with a command like this:

```
exim4 -v recipient@domain.com
From: sender@domain.com
To: recipient@domain.com
Subject: Test email

Body of the email
.
```

Is there a similar command to RETRIEVE emails into the Maildir folder?

NOTE: The emails I want to retrieve are from another email server on the same network. Typically, I use a regular email client to connect to the server via IMAP and SSL.

Comment: I don't understand the questions. Where do you want to retrieve mails from, and what exactly do you want to do with them?

Comment: @Gilles Updated my question. In case it is still not clear, what I want to do is to retrieve copies of all emails sent to a particular email address (received on another email server) so that I can process the body content for other purposes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While it is quite viable to use exim to send emails, your question reads like you are using the wrong tools for what ever your overall goal is. exim cannot retrieve emails from another server, because exim is a mail transfer agent, cf. [RFC 821](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc821). Accessing a users mailbox and retrieving email (what you want to do) is a completely different thing than sending and relaying emails (what exim has been developed for). To sync mailboxes you can use for example [imapsync](http://imapsync.lamiral.info/) or [offlineimap](https://github.com/nicolas33/offlineimap).